One line with a button and img overlapping
I'm trying to make a button that fills the whole width and has an icon on the right side. We're using a shared library for buttons that doesn't allow icons within the element, so I have to use some negative margin hacky solution to get it to work as intended.
The problem I'm running into is that I can't get a width: 100% button to sit on the same line as an icon image.


.foo {
  background: yellow;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
}

.two {
  display: inline;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: green;
}
<div class="foo">
  <button class="one">
    This is a really cool button
  </button>
  <img class="two" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5650/5650380.png">
</div>



Is there some way to keep the two aligned while giving the button 100% of the width?

"The problem I'm running into is that I can't get a width: 100% button to sit on the same line as an icon image." - the reason for that is the whitespace between the tags, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1427878. 100% + 20px + one space character's width - 20px, is more than 100%.

It is possible that way with some coordination trys.
css:
<style>
.foo {
  background: white;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  height: 25px;
}

.two {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -22px;
    left: -5px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
}

</style>

html:
<body>

    <div class="foo">
        
        <button class="one">
            This is a really cool one button.
        </button>

        <div>
            <img class="two" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5650/5650380.png">
        </div>

      </div>
    
</body>


Use flexbox to create a button width 100% and an icon on the right side.


.foo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.one {
  flex: 1;
}

.icon {
  height: 20px;
}
<div class="foo">
  <button class="one">
    This is a really cool button
  </button>
  <img class="icon" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5650/5650380.png">
</div>



